# How to align image and text for my html/css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My full html & css here

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><style>

ul.ItemList, ul.ItemList li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-image: none;
}
ul.ItemList li.Item
{
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-top-color: #ddd;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
}
ul.ItemList div.Desc
{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul.ItemList div.Desc span.Title img
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
}
ul.ItemList div.Desc span
{
    line-height: 2.5;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
ul.ItemList div.Desc span.Title
{
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
ul.ItemList div.Desc span.Title a
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

</style></head>
<body><center><table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"><tbody><tr>

<td align="middle">

 <br />

 <ul class="ItemList">

  <li class="Item">
    <div class="Desc">
     <span class="Title">
     <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a><a href="">Item1</a></span>
    </div>
    Item1
  </li>

  <li class="Item">
    <div class="Desc">
     <span class="Title">
     <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a><a href="">Item2</a></span>
    </div>
    Item2
  </li>

 </ul>
</td>

</tr></tbody></table></center></body></html>
```

It is alright until i changed the size of the image to bigger size, e.g.

```
ul.ItemList div.Desc span.Title img
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
```

How do i improve so that the image will always aligned left nicely with the text at right no matter what is the image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add overflow:auto to ul.ItemList li.Item

```
ul.ItemList li.Item
{
    padding: 15px;
    border-top: #ddd 1px solid;
    overflow:auto
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kXJu/12/)**